# How one define name of fixture in fixtures other then by class name

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fixtures, turbogears2

I'd like to use multiple fixtures in the same test suite to test SQLAlchemy model in various situations. What is the easiest way?

Answer (score 1):

I use fixture methods that are invoked within a test:

```
class TestMyStuff(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.Session = Session(bind=engine)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.Session.rollback()
        self.Session.close()

    def _fixture_one(self):
        self.Session.add_all([
            User(name='ed')
        ])
        self.Session.flush()

    def _fixture_two(self):
        self.Session.add_all([
            Address(street='123 anywhere street')
        ])
        self.Session.flush()

    def test_some_user_thing(self):
        self._fixture_one()
        assert self.Session.query(User.name).first() == (('ed',))

    def test_some_address_thing(self):
        self._fixture_two()
        assert self.Session.query(Address.street).\
            first() == (('123 anywhere street',))
```